# is it possible to apply Spark ML CrossValidatorModel into Flink Streaming data flow?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-flink

Flink is an obvious choice for streaming, however `Spark` has matured `ML pipelines`, is it doable to train model in spark, save it as `CrossValidatorModel` and deploy to streaming data in `Flink`? All in `scala`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink does currently (March 2017, Flink 1.2) not support serving machine learning models for streams. However, this is a feature the community is currently discussing.

Feel free to file a JIRA in Flink to request the feature.

Until there is official support by Flink, there might be other ways to load the model into Flink. (Disclaimer: I'm really not an expert in Spark ML).
From the JavaDocs, it seems that the `CrossValidatorModel` has a method `write()` that returns a `MLWriter` with a `save(String path)` method.

You could build the model in Spark, save the model using the `MLWriter` and then load it again in Flink using the `MLReader` and use it in a stream.

Comment: Does Flink support reading Spark models? If not, both Spark reader and `transform` require a functional Spark cluster... Exporting to some platform independent format could be a better option.

Comment: To answer your question: not yet :) Can you recommend an independent format?

Comment: [(J)PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-spark) worked reasonably well the last time I checked. [MLeap](https://github.com/combust/mleap) is interesting but I am not sure how realistic it is to use it with Flink. This all I know about existing attempts. [PFA](http://dmg.org/pfa/) is promising and there is an [initial Java implementation](https://github.com/opendatagroup/hadrian).

Comment: Thank you for the collection of tools!